# Flask redirect not working with form submitted via POST

Tags: forms, flask

I'm trying to submit the form -- which appears at the bottom of my `books.html` page (see relevant html below) -- to a `/reviews` route, which has a `return redirect(url_for('reviews'))` statement in it. On form submission, however, I receive a `405 Method Not Allowed Error`.

I checked other posts and discovered that, yes, redirect works with the POST method, cross-checked my methods for the submission of forms required to reach the `/books` and `/reviews` routes, plus their form action attributes and methods associated therewith. All seemed fine. I still cannot unearth the error.

The desired behavior is that users submit a review via the form on the `/books` page below, and the page updates and displays the review, rating, and avg. rating. The logic in the `/reviews` route should do the processing and updating.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><strong>Username</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Review</strong></th>
                <th class="text-center"><strong>Rating</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for review in reviews %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ review.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ review.reviews }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ review.rating }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
         <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Average Rating</th>
                <td colspan="1"></td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ avg_rating }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

<form action="{{ url_for('reviews') }}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <label class="mr-3">Rate This Title & Write a Review</label>
                <label class="mr-3 form-check-label">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bookrating" id="onestar" value="1">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                </label>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="userreview" type="text"/>
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="bookid" value="{{ books.id }}" type="hidden"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

{% endblock %}

@app.route("/reviews", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def reviews():
    book_id = request.form.get("bookid")
    register_id = session["user_id"]
    books = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = :id", {"id": book_id}).fetchone()

    reviews = db.execute("SELECT register.username, reviews, rating FROM reviews JOIN register ON reviews.book_id = :id AND reviews.user_id = register.id", {"id": book_id})

    avg_rating = db.execute("SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),0) FROM reviews WHERE book_id = :book_id", {"book_id": book_id}).scalar()

    user_reviews = db.execute("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE user_id = :id AND book_id = :book_id", {"id": register_id, "book_id": book_id}).fetchone()

    if not user_reviews:
        target_review = request.form.get("userreview")

        db.execute("INSERT INTO reviews (book_id, reviews, user_id) VALUES (:book_id, :reviews, :user_id)", {"book_id": book_id, "reviews": target_review, "user_id": register_id})

        db.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('reviews'))

    else:
        return render_template("books.html", books=books, reviews=reviews)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and add "GET" to your methods:

```
 @app.route("/reviews", methods=["GET", "POST"])
 @login_required
 def reviews():
     book_id = request.form.get("bookid")
     register_id = session["user_id"]
```

Could be that the implementation of redirect in flask changes the request to a GET request and your reviews route does not allow it

Comment: I don't think that's the default behavior (based on my review of other material).  That said, upon playing with the insertion of GET anyway, I think my problems are a bit bigger than url_redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you want to redirect to reviews function (which is route /reviews). But your methods only post. I believe that redirect need GET methods to load some page.

Comment: I'll take another look at some examples. Thanks!